# jquery popup plugin

Tags: jquery, html, popup, anchor

i'm using a popup plugin for jquery that will open a popup window using the href in anchor.

example `<a href="/some/site?hello=hi" class="popup">link</a>`

on my page i can have an unlimited number of these because each one will be pointing to the same site but a different get variable (like page=1235)

problem i'm having is by using the class in the jquery `$(".popup").popUp();`
its activiating every single anchor with the class popup.

i only want the one clicked on but i dont want to have to write a different id for each anchor...

anyway around this ?

the link to the plugin is http://plugins.jquery.com/project/PopupWindow

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
//1st popup
    $(".popup").eq(1).popUp();
//2nd popup
    $(".popup").eq(2).popUp();
```

You need to differentiate between the elements, $(".popup") returns a collection of elements - each element with the "popup" class - therefore .popUp() is run on each.

Comment: sounds good. 

but this would require me to have a line of javascript for every link generated ?

Comment: Actually i have looked at the plugin code and this doesnt appear to be the case . the plug in applies a function using that individual anchors information to that anchor. it uses the collection to find every anchor you want to apply some overall popup functionality to. but still allow it to be customized by the link.... in short i'm stumped.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you just tried to explain. Have you tried the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. `$(".popup")` returns a collection of objects, not a single object, thus, calling `popUp()` on the collection will apply the effect to each element in it. The "way around" is to think exactly what you want to achieve and using appropriate code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery tooltip. Use this link http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html